# Loop different functions with different timing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, setinterval

I have some functions, for example, *`afoo()`, `bfoo()` and `cfoo()`*, I want that functions run simultaneously/paralel in a loop with different timing.

Example:

`afoo()` --> run one time every 5 minutes

`bfoo()` --> run one time every 10 minutes

`cfoo()` --> run one time every hour

Is there anyway to do that? Maybe with SetInterval()?

Comment: `setInterval` should work.. What is the problem?

Comment: *Is there anyway to do that?* **Yes**. *Maybe with SetInterval()?* **Precisely**. Whats the issue again?

Comment: setInterval seems ok, look at this answer because if you want a bit more control over what exactly happens and when, setTimeout can maybe be an alternative : https://stackoverflow.com/a/729943/2143734

Comment: setInterval is better for various reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval

Comment: There are no issues, just asking. I tried SetInterval and work fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) method to call a function on every fixed time delay, in the most case it's used in conjunction with [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) method to stop the repeated calls, here is an example:

```
var interval = setInterval( function () {
    afoo( function (err) {
        // clear interval if an error occured
        if ( err ) {
            console.log(err);
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    });
}, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

If you want more control then use [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) module, it has the same [cron pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) used by linux systems, Example:

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

// run afoo function every 15 min
var job = new CronJob('00 15 * * * *', afoo);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have look on node-cron!